# Should I use the word "degree" or the symbol ° for expressing angles in a scientific text?

Tags: symbols

I hope this is the correct StackExchange to ask a question like this.

For a scientific text (in computer science), which is the correct way of expressing angles (e.g. the yaw, pitch and roll angle of an airplane or any 3D model) - Should I use the word "degree" or the symbol "°" (^\circ in latex)?

Also, would I use "degree" or "degrees" (plural)?

Example sentences would be:

- The yaw angle ranges from -60 degree to +60 degree.
- We show experimental results for the images with 10 and 20 degree pitch angle.
- X works well for angles smaller than 10 degrees roll angle.

Comment: Belongs on Writers or Academia.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest using the word instead of the symbol in written text (and reserve the symbol for drawings and such). I guess it is a matter of style, but the use of the symbol in text tends to confuse me with degrees as mentioned in temperature.

As for using degree or degrees, do **not** use the plural whenever specifying more than 1!

When you specific more than 1 degree on its own, yes, you would write 20 **degrees**.

But since you are also talking about angles, a 20 **degree** angle is correct.

So in your example sentences (taking into account msam's comment about the nist recommendation):

> The yaw angle ranges from -60 **degrees** to +60 **degrees**.
>   We show experimental results for the images with 10 **degree** and 20 **degree** pitch angle.
>   X works well for roll angles smaller than 10 **degrees**.

Comment: [nist](http://www.nist.gov/pml/wmd/metric/upload/SP-811-2008-Checklist-Reviewing-Manuscripts.pdf) recommends always stating the unit after the value ie: "The yaw angle ranges from -60 degrees to +60 degrees" (or -60° to +60°)

Comment: But that same NIST guide states *Unit symbols (or names) are not modified by the addition of subscripts or other information* which I interpret to mean that `degrees` is frowned upon

Comment: @High Performance Mark: The standard abbreviation for *degree* is ° or deg — I don't think you'd expect to see it spelled out in a scientific publication, but if was it would be pluralized. The NIST guide gives 2°3'4" as an example.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark [Please ‘never’ use   on ELU](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/4722).

Comment: @tchrist, sorry, I used my typewriter for that word.

Answer (score 2):

I hardly ever appreciate answers of the type 'Do it this way'. Says me.

[SPORTSCIENCE](http://www.sportsci.org/jour/9901/wghstyle.html#abbreviations) may not be a widely recognised authority, but certainly cites one:

> Use the following Systeme Internationale (SI) abbreviations for units
>   of measurement (Young, 1987) [APA uses some of these abbreviations.]
>
> meter m
>
> millisecond ms
>
> gram g
>
> second s
>
> kilogram kg
>
> minute min
>
> mole mol
>
> hour h
>
> liter L (not l)
>
> day d
>
> milliliter ml
>
> week wk
>
> degree °C

And another article, at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-SI_units_mentioned_in_the_SI) has:

> Units officially accepted for use with the SI: degree °   plane angle
>   (dimensionless unit)  1° = (π / 180) rad

Comment: and [here's](http://www.bipm.org/en/si/si_brochure/chapter4/table6.html) the direct reference from bipm

Comment: "Do it this way" has advantages for technical writing that needs to  be clear and unambiguous for foreign readers and might need to be read in 100years time

Comment: @mgb But the content of answers here (which is what I was referring to) should be guided by the suggestions in the help centre:  Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful, **but do try to mention any limitations, assumptions or simplifications in your answer** [bolding mine]. "Use 'degrees' " in answer to this question is a poor and opinionated answer, not required even by the pretty dictatorial people at BIPM. If you want me to spell it out, _don't present answers which are inadequate but which sound like they're papal edicts. And give authoritative references_ .

Answer (score 2):

This is a matter that should be addressed by the house style of the publisher.

For instance, some publishers will insist upon the abbreviation *deg.*, others upon the symbol °, and others that you spell out *degree* — and then some publisher may insist that you convert all angles to radians.

If you don’t have a publisher yet, personally, I’d recommend spelling out *degree* unless you are using it many, many times in each chapter.

Comment: To clarify further - if you're self-publishing, pick a style manual and try to follow it. I prefer the *Chicago Manual of Style*, but there are many others that are widely respected - APA, MLA, Associated Press, etc.

Comment: [Please ‘never’ use   on ELU](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/4722).

Comment: Highlighting a style violation in a posting about style manuals? You must have chuckled evilly while making that edit. Noted. I was trying to follow the StackExchange style, not realizing the ELU had separate style considerations. Plus one in thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use ° anywhere you would otherwise consider using a symbol or abbreviation.

Use *degree* or *degrees* anywhere you would generally spell out other units.

If in doubt, use ° when using digits and the word when using words, hence *180°* and *a hundred and eighty degrees*.

If any use of an abbreviation looks ambiguous, then avoid it, though this is unlikely with ° since the only other use is with temperatures* which aren't likely to be confused, and there aren't really any similar symbols in English. (In languages which use º for ordinals there's more of a risk, since that symbol looks similar or even identical in some fonts).

Repetition reduces the risk of ambiguity, so if you have a large number of uses, you can be more confident in using °, and also gain more too (in reducing the number of times you would repeat the word *degrees*).

If the text is scientific or technical, you can be more confident again in such a use.

I would probably use ° in all of your examples.

*Specifically °C and °F, though it could be worth avoiding near K as some people miswrite K as °K.